# Is it possible to use the estimator.predict on a new test set after cross validation?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, logistic-regression

I have a new question about scikit for you.

Classification problem, logistic regression as estimator.
I have my X dataset, with my features.

I want to use my algorithm through cross validation and I have two ways: I split manually my dataset in 5 subsets, end I iterate for 5 times leaving every time a different set for testing. I obtain my scores, but what I want now is the average of the coefficients to use with the estimator to predict on a new dataset. I read somewhere on stackoverflow that it's possible to pass the coefficients to the scikit logistic regression estimator.

The otherway is to use `cross_val_score`:

```
lrmodel=LogisticRegression(penalty='l2',C=1)    
cv.cross_val_score(lrmodel, Xf, y, cv=5,scoring='log_loss', verbose=0)
```

gives me the cross-entropy after a cross validation estimation. But what if now I want to use the average coefficients and use the estimator for a new prediction on my new yet unlabeled dataset?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just re-fit the estimator to the full set after the cross-validation?

Comment: The risk of overfitting would be avoided with a new fit?

Comment: Cross-validation doesn't guard against overfitting, it just *measures* it. Also, the estimator's variance can be expected to decrease if you give it more data with the same settings.

Comment: @Lars, thank you for your help! Do you have any suggested reading about cross validation and overfitting? How does cross-entropy measure overfitting? Am I confused? I thought that with cross validation and averaging on the scores and coeffs I would obtain something less fit for the specific training set.


Furthermore: can you tell me why my cross entropy using cross_val_score is negative while if I use a manual cross validation, creating 5 bins, calculate the cross entropy on every test set and then averaging I have the same final cross entropy in magnitude but positive?

Comment: `cross_val_score` flips signs on loss functions. That's a known issue.